# CreateFile Entry Not Found in Kernel32.dll (P/Invoke from C# using Mono on Raspberry Pi)

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, mono, pinvoke

I am getting "System.EntryPointNotFoundException: CreateFile" when running the code below using mono on a Raspberry Pi.  The code executes correctly when run from Windows.  I also tried using "CreateFileA".  Any thoughts, anyone?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MainClass {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        IntPtr hdl = CreateFile(
            "/dev/fb1", 
            FileAccess.ReadWrite,
            FileShare.None, 
            IntPtr.Zero, 
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAttributes.Normal,
            IntPtr.Zero);
        if (hdl == (IntPtr)(-1))
            throw new Exception("Error opening device.");
        CloseHandle(hdl);
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess access,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare share,
         IntPtr securityAttributes, // optional SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES struct or IntPtr.Zero
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes flagsAndAttributes,
         IntPtr templateFile);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern void CloseHandle(IntPtr hdl);

}
```

The exception

> /home/shared $ sudo mono ConsoleApp6.exe
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: CreateFile
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) MainClass.CreateFile(string,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,intptr,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAttributes,intptr)
>
> at MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in
>   <5329dec93702493383eb2a8ef2339b6f>:0 [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED
>   EXCEPTION: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: CreateFile
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MainClass.CreateFile(string,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,intptr,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAttributes,intptr)
>
> at MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in
>   <5329dec93702493383eb2a8ef2339b6f>:0

Comment: This is a Windows specific dll and function, don't believe that you can use it on a Raspberry Pi. You can try to look at dll maps and p/invoke in [mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/)

Comment: Doh.  You are absolutely right.  What I managed to do was to use P/Invoke against libc to do what I needed.